# How to get mac os x login username and password in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This might be a silly question considering that am a new to xcode. I know how to get the username through NSUserName, just can't figure out how to get the password.

Comment: Brace yourself, down votes are coming.

Comment: At least give some explanation and vote down. If you don't know, its ok, I don't know either but just don't vote down when you can't even explain why.

Comment: It would a **massive** security flaw (any app might access your credentials)

Comment: What purpose do you need the user's password for? For any legitimate purpose there's likely to be a better way

Comment: Not even MacOS X knows the password that you use to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apps can't access the password -- on no OS I am aware of :)

it would open a BIG hole in the security of your mac/phone/pc

---

### alternative

if you aren't going for the appstore you can ask for elevated rights for your app (which would show a system popup for the user to enter his credentials)

Comment: Thanks Daij-Djan for the insight. like I said, am new to this, just looking for opportunity to learn so I greatly appreciate your answer. I will now delete the question.